# ¿Por qué Angular no recompila el proyecto?

Tags: angular

```
Angular CLI: 6.2.4
Node: 8.10.0
OS: linux x64
Angular: 6.1.9
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... http, language-service, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, router

Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.8.4
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.8.4
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.8.4
@angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.8.4
@angular-devkit/core              0.8.4
@angular-devkit/schematics        0.8.4
@angular/cli                      6.2.4
@ngtools/webpack                  6.2.4
@schematics/angular               0.8.4
@schematics/update                0.8.4
rxjs                              6.2.2
typescript                        2.9.2
webpack                           4.20.2
```

Estoy trabajando en Ubuntu 16.04 y esas son mis especificaciones.

Mi problema es que hay veces que angular-cli no me detecta cambios en los archivos que no tengo agregados en mi `app.module` pero si los tengo en otro módulo. Esto no siempre pasa, pero tengo que parar el servidor y volver a levantarlo para que detecte cambios en los archivos declarados en otros módulos. ¿Hay una manera de solucionar esto? Nunca me había pasado en Mac OS o Windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hola Akko por lo visto alguien ya se enfrentó a este problema en Ubuntu 16.04, la solución radica en ajustar la configuración de los Inotify Watches en linux. Puedes chequearlo [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44494820)

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias!